# python convert list with sub lists to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Hello i'm new to python.

i'm working with lists in python and i want to Convert a `list` named **graph** to `dictionnary` **graph** in `PYTHON`.

my have `list` :

```js
graph = [
    ['01 Mai', 
      [
        ['Musset', 5],
        ['Place 11 Decembre 1960', 4],
        ["Sidi M'hamed", 3],
        ['El Hamma (haut)', 6]
      ]
    ], 
    ['Musset',
      [
        ['Place 11 Decembre 1960', 4],
        ["Sidi M'hamed", 3],
        ['El Hamma (haut)', 6], 
        ["Jardin d'Essai (haut)", 10]
      ],
    ]
]
```

i want the list to be a dictionary like that :

```js
graph = {
  '01 mai':{
      'Musset':5, 
      'Place 11 Decembre 1960':4,
      "Sidi M'hamed":3,
      "El Hamma (haut)":6,
      },
  'Musset':{
    'Place 11 Decembre 1960':4,
    "Sidi M'hamed":3,
    "El Hamma (haut)":6,
    "Jardin d'Essai (haut)": 10,
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened to `"Place du"`? Have you tried writing code yet?

Comment: How did `Place du 1er Mai` become `01 mai`? Also - are you sure that's the end structure you want - it looks like you could potentially run the risk of duplicate keys...

Comment: it's the same thing

Comment: Also, please correct the list `graph`, some brackets are missing.

Comment: @ilyesBourouba `1er Mai` and `01 mai` are definitely not the same thing... it would appear you're expecting some kind of thing to occur there that's not defined... is it okay if the output remains as `1er Mai` ?

Comment: it was a mistake in my question that's all, '01 mai" =  '1er mai', and i did correct it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple dict comprehension would do:

```py
as_dict = {k: dict(v) for k,v in graph}
```

[Playground](https://www.online-python.com/njzoZagLfc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to handle input of unknown depth:

```
graph = [['01 Mai', [['Musset', 5], ['Place 11 Decembre 1960', 4], ["Sidi M'hamed", 3], ['El Hamma (haut)', 6]]], ['Musset', [['Place 11 Decembre 1960', 4], ["Sidi M'hamed", 3], ['El Hamma (haut)', 6], ["Jardin d'Essai (haut)", 10]]]]
def to_dict(d):
  return {a:b if not isinstance(b, list) else to_dict(b) for a, b in d}

print(to_dict(graph))
```

Output:

```
{'01 Mai': {'Musset': 5, 'Place 11 Decembre 1960': 4, "Sidi M'hamed": 3, 'El Hamma (haut)': 6}, 'Musset': {'Place 11 Decembre 1960': 4, "Sidi M'hamed": 3, 'El Hamma (haut)': 6, "Jardin d'Essai (haut)": 10}}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be:

```
for item in graph:
    d[item[0]] = {record[0]: record[1] for record in item[1]}
```